# Swift, Why are the memory sizes of 'String' and 'String?' the same?

Tags: swift, string, option-type

Case `Int`, `Int?`
I realized that in the case of optional variables, a bit is needed to check if nil, so it comes out 1 byte larger.

But why is the memory size of `String` and `String?` the same?
Not only `String`, but also `Array`, `Dictionary`, and `Set` produce the same results.

Is it because they support Copy-on-Write?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axdvb.png)

I searched Apple's official documentation, but couldn't find any results, so I'm asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, `Wrapped?`, aka `Optional<Wrapped>` is an enum:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case some(Wrapped)
    case none
}
```

This is an enum that only has one case that has an associated value. Its memory layout is described in the "single payload enums" section in the type layout documentation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#single-payload-enums).

> If an enum has a single case with a data type and one or more no-data cases (a "single-payload" enum), then the case with data type is represented using the data type's binary representation, with added zero bits for tag if necessary. If the data type's binary representation has extra inhabitants, that is, bit patterns with the size and alignment of the type but which do not form valid values of that type, they are used to represent the no-data cases, with extra inhabitants in order of ascending numeric value matching no-data cases in declaration order.

In other words, while `String` is 128 bits in size, not all 128-bit bit patterns represent a valid `String`. There are some bit patterns that are invalid `String`s. The invalid bit-patterns are the "extra inhabitants". Since these are invalid values of `String`, they can be used to represent the `none` case (aka `nil`) of a `String?`.

The same applies for `Array`/`Set`/`Dictionary`.

As an experiment, try thinking of some 128-bit values in the form of a pair of `Int`s (i.e. `(Int, Int)`), then you can try `unsafeBitCast`ing them to `String`. Some of them will succeed, and some of them will fail.

Another example of a type with extra inhabitants would be `Bool`. There are only two possible values of `Bool`, but its size and alignment are both 1 byte. It has 254 extra inhabitants!

On the other hand, `Int` has no extra inhabitants - no matter how you arrange the bits, they always represent a valid value of `Int`. So the size of `Int?` needs to be bigger than an `Int` to represent `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Since optional is implemented by enum, When the associated value has a tagged pointer,
The extra bit required for the enum is stored in the spare bits of the tagged pointer.
https://forums.swift.org/t/how-do-i-implemented-a-tagged-pointer-in-swift/24729

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).